# How to create a second drawer in jetpack compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I've searched for this a lot but could not find it, We can use scaffold and put our drawer content inside of it or we can use ModalDrawer but there's just no option to make the drawer to come from the right to left , I want it to be swiped from right to left

I want two drawers left and right but even though you can create a bottom drawer , you can't create a simple right to left drawer !

Comment: Inside the `ModalDrawer` there is a `Box` with `Modifier.swipeable( reverseDirection = isRtl)`. It is not possibile to change this value without changing the rtl direction. You can try to clone the code changing this parameter.

Comment: If you are able to implement two modal drawer on single screen then pls share the code.

Comment: the other drawer doesn't work yet , wait for it to be implemented properly , follow this :  https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/174514369

Comment: If you try some other hacky way , it won't look natural !